# Compute operator norm of $l^1$ bounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

I have a problem with the following exercise:

We have the operator $T: l^1 \to l^1$ given by

$$T(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)=\left(\left(1-\frac11\right)x_1, \left(1-\frac12\right)x_2, \dots\right)$$  for $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)$ in $l^1$. Showing that this operator is bounded is easy, but  I am really desperate with showing that the norm $\|T\| = 1$.

I know that for bounded operators the norm is defined as $\|T\|=\sup{\left\{\|T(x)\|: \|x\| \le 1\right\}}$.

I am also wondering if there exists a x in $ l^1$ such that $\|x\|=1 $

and $\|T(x)\|= \|T\|$

Thank you! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the norm of the operators](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235978/finding-the-norm-of-the-operators)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First observe that $\|T\|\le 1$.

Fix a large $n$ and let $x_n=(\dots,0,1,0,\dots)$ with $1$ exactly at the $n$th position and $0$ everywhere else. We have $Tx_n = (1-\frac1n) x_n$, $\|x_n\|=1$ and $\|Tx_n\| = 1-\frac1n.$
This shows $\|T\|\ge 1- \frac1n$. Now let $n\to\infty$ to conclude $\|T\|\ge 1$.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but why does this show that ||T|| >= 1-1/n ??

Comment: Because $\|T\|=\sup\{ \|Tx\| \,:\,\|x\|=1\} \ge \|T x_n\| = 1-\frac1n$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\left|\left| T((x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}})\right|\right|_{\ell_1}=\left|\left| \left(\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)x_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\right|\right|_{\ell_1}=\sum_j \left|\left(1-\frac{1}{j}\right)x_j\right|\leqslant \sum_j |x_j |=||(x_n )_{n\in\mathbb{N}} ||_{\ell_1}$$

hence

$$||T||\leqslant 1$$

but $$||T||\geqslant \sup_j ||Te_j || =\sup_j \left(1-\frac{1}{j}\right) =1$$

Thus $$||T||=1.$$

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question, could you help me with part 2?

Comment: No there does not exist a $x$ such that  $||x||=1$ and $||Tx||=1$

Comment: Thats what I was assuming too, but could you give me small proof for that?

Comment: $\sum (1 - \frac{1}{n}) |x_n| < \sum |x_n| \leq 1$ therefore  $||Tx|| <1$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Define $X^n = (\underbrace{\frac{1}{n}, \dots ,\frac{1}{n}}_{n}, 0, 0, ...)$. Show that for every $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N$ such that $||X^N||_{l^1} > 1-\epsilon$, thus proving the statement.

Comment: Thank you, could you help me with part 2 as well?